# Display Pop up using nested datalist details

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, popup, nested-datalist

My first 'Datalist1' retrieves some values from database i.e.,

**Bus Route ID,
Vehicle number, 
Trip date, 
Bus source station name,
Bus Destination name**

Another 'nested Datalist' which is placed inside datalist1 displays Bus icons of stages according to the number of stages between source and destination.
I succeeded to retrieving the data correctly and displayed a pop up using the above retrieved details.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" CellSpacing="3" RepeatLayout="Table" BackColor="LightGray" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_DataBinding">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <table class="table">
      <tr style="background-color : #b62a26;  font-size:medium ; font-family:Verdana; height:40px ">
        <td style="padding-left:5px">
          <asp:Label ID="lblTrip" runat="server" Text="TripID:" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="width:900px; ">
          <b> <asp:Label ID="lblTripID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TripID") %>' ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></b></td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: white;  font-size:small  ; font-family:Verdana; height:60px;  ">
        <td colspan="2">
          <b>RouteID: </b></b>
          <asp:Label ID="lblRouteID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RouteID") %>'></asp:Label>

          <b>Vehicle NO: </b>
          <asp:Label ID="lblVehicleNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VehicleNo") %>'></asp:Label>
          <b>TripDate: </b>
          <asp:Label ID="lblTripDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TripDate") %>'></asp:Label>
          <b>From: </b>
          <asp:Label ID="lblFromStage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromStage") %>'></asp:Label>
          <b>To: </b>
          <asp:Label ID="lblToStage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ToStage") %>'></asp:Label>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: white;  font-size:small ; font-family:Verdana; height:10px ">
        <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td>

          <div id="activeBus" style="line-height: 0px; float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <asp:DataList ID="innerDataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="10" CellSpacing="3" BackColor="white">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center">
                  <table>
                    <tr style=" align-items:center ">
                      <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgactiveBtn" runat="server" src="\images\ActiveRed.png" Width="15px" Height="15px" OnClick="imgBtn_Click" ToolTip="Track Details" />
                        <%--    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" src="\images\ActiveRed.png" runat="server" Style="cursor: pointer"  Width="15px" Height="15px" OnClientClick="return LoadDiv(this.src);"/> --%>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <b><asp:Label ID="lblStageName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StageName") %>' Font-Size="XX-Small" Font-Names="Verdana" ></asp:Label></b>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </asp:Panel>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
          </div>

          <div id="inactiveBus" style="line-height: 0px; float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <asp:DataList ID="innerDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="10" CellSpacing="3" BackColor="white" OnItemDataBound="innerDataList_ItemDataBound">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center">
                  <table>
                    <tr style=" align-items:center ">
                      <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imginactiveBtn" runat="server" src="\images\InActive.png" Width="15px" Height="15px" OnClick="imgBtn_Click" ToolTip="Not Reached yet!" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <b><asp:Label ID="lblStageName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StageName") %>' Font-Size="XX-Small" ForeColor="#CCCCFF"></asp:Label></b>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </asp:Panel>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
        <br />
        <b>RouteID:</b> <span id="RouteID1"></span> <label id="lblEmpId"></label>
        <br />
        <b>TripDate:</b> <span id="TripDate1"></span> <label id="lblEmpName"></label>
        <br />
        <b>Stage Name:</b> <span id="StageName1"></span><label id="lblEmpLocation"></label>
        <br />
        <b>Scheduled Arrival:</b> <span id="Scheduled_Time1"></span>
       <br />
        <b>Reached On:</b> <span id="Arrival_Time1"></span>
       <br /><br />
    </div>
```

Jquery code is:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id*=imginactiveBtn]", function () {
  $("#RouteID1").html($(".RouteID", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
  $("#TripDate1").html($(".TripDate", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
  $("#StageName1").html($(".StageName", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
  $("#Scheduled_Time1").html($(".Scheduled_Time", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
  $("#Arrival_Time1").html($(".Arrival_Time", $(this).closest("tr")).html());

  // Get the Current Row and its values.
  var currentRow = $(this).parents("tr");
  var RId = currentRow.find("span[id*='lblRouteID']").text();
  var TDate = currentRow.find("span[id*='lblTripDate']").text();
  var SName = currentRow.find("span[id*='lblStageName']").text();
  // Populate labels inside the dailog.
  $("#lblEmpId").text(RId);
  $("#lblEmpName").text(TDate);
  $("#lblEmpLocation").text(SName);

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Track Vehicle at <em>" + SName + "</em>",
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    modal: true
  });

  return false;
});
```

For example let us assume on 12/10/2017, 2 Trips were active with RouteID's 1 & 2, and each Routes has 3 stages.

When the first stage of route 1 is clicked Popup should display:

```
Route ID: Route1 
TripDate: 12/10/2017 
Stage Name: Stage1
```

When second icon is clicked Popup should should display

```
RouteID: Route1
TripDate: 12/10/2017 
Stage: Stage2 and so on...
```

Similarly when Stages of Route2 is clicked

```
Route ID: Route2 
TripDate: 12/10/2017 
Stage Name: Stage1
```

and when he clicks second stage of Route 2

```
Route ID: Route2 
TripDate: 12/10/2017 
Stage Name: Stage2 and so on.....
```

But Popup displays:

```
RouteID: Route1Route2 
TripDate: 12/10/201712/10/2017 
StageName: Stage1Stage2Stage3Stage1Stage2Stage3
```

for all the 3 stages of Route1 and for all the 3 stages of Route2.

How can i resolve this. Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: without seeing the HTML and its contents, it's very difficult to say. That code snippet on its own doesn't say very much, and it also looks invalid - is that a direct copy of your code? We need some context

Comment: Just added the code. I'm new to this. Thanks

Comment: A few questions: 1. did you miss a part of the jQuery (the event handler line)? There's an extra `});` at the end which suggests that this code is wrapped by another function. 2. What do the first 5 lines of jQuery do? (`$("#RouteID1").html($(".RouteID", $(this).closest("tr")).html());)` etc? I ask because there are no elements in your markup which match the selectors .RouteID, .TripDate etc. So it looks like they won't populate with anything

Comment: 3. I still can't see your actual, final, generated HTML, which is what jQuery works on, rather than the ASPX markup which is evaluated on the server and turned into HTML. So it's still not 100% clear what the jQuery will find or what it will do. Can you post the actual page source instead please? (you can get it by doing View Source in your browser on the finished page). That will also give me some sample data to work with. I know the desired output but not the original material it's derived from. 5. Does the popup display the same thing whichever icon you click on, or for particular ones?

Comment: For the first point 1.Yeah i have removed                                                                                   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", "[id*=imginactiveBtn]", function () { and ark up code i have just added

Comment: Ok I've edited that into the question for you, thanks. Are you able to answer the other questions please, and edit the question appropriately? I'm sure the solution is probably quite simple, once we have got the proper information to understand what's happening.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `var currentRow = $(this).parents("tr");` is the problem - it must be returning a `<tr>` which encompasses all your routes, and therefore the .find operations find all elements matching the ID selector, not just a single one. Note that the `<tr>` which actually contains those labels is not a an ancestor of the image button. But I can't see that parent `<tr>`, presumably the `<asp:DataList` is generating some more tables above the ones you've explicitly generated.

Comment: Sir Added the code now.

Comment: No you haven't, thats just the markup of the dialog box. I don't really need that. I'm talking about the generated HTML which results from ASP.NET having processed all that `<asp:DataList` stuff and generated some HTML which a browser can actually understand. That's what happens when you execute an ASPX page. `<asp:DataList` and all that is not sent to the browser - that browser doesn't know what it means. ASP.NET turns it into real HTML first. jQuery runs in the browser and can only work on that final HTML, not on the ASPX markup - it never even sees the ASPX.

Comment: Since the problem is with what jQuery is reading from the HTML, I need to see that finished HTML in order to properly answer the question, then I will have the same information that jQuery has, and also some sample data contained within it. Above in my question 3 I told you how to find the generated HTML using the browser (via the View Source feature built into every browser). Please find it and display it here.

Comment: Regarding point 5: Yes it displays the same thing for every icon click

Comment: Point 3: HTML source code is here http://rkmantada.blogspot.in/2017/10/html-xmlns-httpwww.html

Comment: Project outpput is here: http://rkmantada.blogspot.in/2017/10/project-output.html

Comment: Please put (the relevant parts of) the code **in the question** and format it properly. That's unreadable without proper indentation, and also the question (according to site rules) should be self-contained, so any relevant code should be within the question itself. Sorry to be pedantic but that's how it is - the question is not just for your benefit, it's a resource for future readers, who will need to see the relevant info directly. Also external links can disappear or go stale or change, outside the control of SO, and that might make the question make no sense in future.

Comment: You put your previous code into the question, so there's no reason you can't put this new stuff in. You can remove the current `<asp:DataList` etc, but keep the jQuery, as that's important. We don't need all the outer html tags and the serialised viewstate, just that part which is the equivalent of what's in the existing code (i.e. everything within the DataList1 element)